# Two entities have reference to third entity. How to map it?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to find best solution for situation described below.

I have entity called **Address** which shows like this.

```
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@Entity
public class Address extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

I have two different entites called **Customer** and **Company**. Both these entites should contain **Address**.

**Customer** has one address.

```
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="owner")
    private Address address;
```

**Company** has list of addresses.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
public class Company extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    private List<Address> address;
```

How to make mapping on **Address** entity?

Comment: Given this design, Address shouldn't know its owner. And you should have a join column in Company and Customer, not in Address (i.e. each customer should have a foreign key to its address, and same for Company).

Comment: JB Nizet: Thank you very much for answer but i think that you overlooked connection between company and address. There is possible to have more address for company. If I am right i will need one more table to map this 1 to N connection?

Comment: The same goes for this association. Addresses shouldn't know about their company. The OneToMany should be mapped using the default mapping, using a join table between Company and Address.